# Multiple Group by clause

Tags: grouping

I need to count the number of students based on class_code and course_code and at the same time count the number of students only based on course. I need two results.

Here is my code

```
SELECT 
 Class_code,Course_code, Count(OEN)
FROM section52D    
GROUP BY Class_code, Course_code
```

It solves the first part but I still need count based on course_code.

Comment: Format the code using backticks (`) so that your question is more readable. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Sql Server 2008, I hope this helps you:

```
SELECT Class_code,Course_code, Count(OEN) as count_basedOn_classAndCourse
into #temp
FROM section52D
GROUP BY Class_code, Course_code

SELECT Course_code, Count(OEN) as count_basedOn_Course
into #temp2
FROM section52D
GROUP BY Course_code

select * from #temp1
select * from #temp2

select t1.Course_Code , t1.Class_Code, 
       t1.count_basedOn_classAndCourse, 
       t2.count_basedOn_Course
from #temp1 t1
left outer join #temp2 t2 on t1.Course_Code = t2.Course_Code
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
SELECT Class_code,
       Course_code,
       (select Count(OEN) FROM section52D) as totalOEN 
from section52D
GROUP BY Class_code, Course_code
```